# Use /bin/bash for %x in Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell

```
%x{ echo hi }
```

seems to fork off `/bin/sh`. I'd prefer `/bin/bash`. Is there a way to set that? The best thing I can think of is

```
%x {/bin/bash -c 'echo hi'}
```

but that doesn't to report output back like it should. Also, it's a general thing: I just never want `/bin/sh`, I *always* want `/bin/bash`

Comment: "seems to fork off `/bin/bash`. I'd prefer `/bin/bash`" - ehm?

Comment: Ahh, shoot. Of course, it forks /bin/sh. Fixed.

Comment: As a policy in our group at work, we only write scripts using /bin/sh. It's more stable/portable. I've never found a reason to use a different way.

Comment: @the Tin Man. I disagree. /bin/bash exists everywhere and behaves the same everywhere.  /bin/sh is dash on ubuntu, but a simplified bash on osx, and heaven only knows what /bin/sh is on plan9.

Comment: @nes1983 When writing a script that targets `/bin/sh`, you restrict yourself to the POSIX standard. You don't use features that rely on `/bin/sh` being linked to a particular shell. There are some significant differences in how certain `bash` features work between versions (`bash` currently has 4 options `compat31`, `compat32`, `compat40`, `compat41` to make the current version of `bash` fully compatible with one previous version or another).

Comment: @chepner: Yea … and if you do a mistake, you won't find out until a plan9 user sends you an angry email. Or … you just use /bin/bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the default shell `/bin/sh` is hardcoded in order to be as portable as possible. To use bash, you could do something like this:

```
def bash(cmd)
  IO.popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]) {|io| io.read}
end

output = bash %q(cat <<< "hello world")
p output
```

```
"hello world\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

Write this somewhere in your Ruby code.

```
ENV["SHELL"] = "/bin/bash"
```

Comment: @Geoffroy Using double quotes for string literal is the standard, and is the form used in `inspect`. There is nothing wrong with using it without interpolation. It is preferable. Also, you should not edit other people's code content (even if it is wrong) except for fixing white spaces (indentation), comments, etc.

Comment: okay, thanks for the precision. But doesn't string interpolation takes significantly more time ? (relatively)

Comment: @sawa It is not working for me: `ruby -e 'ENV["SHELL"]="/bin/bash"; %x[cat <<< foo]" produces the error `sh: 1: Syntax error: ...` which means that the command `cat <<< foo` is executed by `/bin/sh`, I'm missing something?

Comment: @toro2k In my environment, `ENV["SHELL"]` is `/bin/bash` from the beginning, but in the error message, it shows `sh`, so I think that part is constantly `sh` irrespective of the shell interpreter.

Comment: @Geoffroy Why not ask that as a question?

Comment: @toro2k If in doubt, maybe you can try something that would be grammatical under sh but not under bash, or the other way around.

Comment: @sawa It is what I've already done, `cat <<< foo` is not a valid command for `/bin/sh` (it is dash on my system) and it is valid for bash.

Comment: @Geoffroy I recall seeing some benchmarks that show that `"` is actually faster than `'` if interpolation is not involved.