# How to make Ruby compatible with bash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, bash, shell

I have a ruby script that uses `open3` to run shell commands from inside the script and I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and bash.

When I run that script it produces errors such as `0: sh: 2: pushd: not found`. I searched and one thing I found was https://stackoverflow.com/a/17044484/5553963 which suggested that we use `ENV["SHELL"] = "/bin/bash"` but when I checked my environment variable I already have that:

```
$ printenv "SHELL"
/bin/bash
```

How I can make this script working on my machine?

The first part of that script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'open3'

def run(i, cmd)
    res = ""
    Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, thread|
```

And my ruby version: `ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`

Comment: What is `cmd`? As a note, `popen3` will launch `sh` and *not* `bash` and [I'm not sure it pays attention to the `SHELL` environment variable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Process.html#method-c-spawn). Using `popen3` with separated arguments is the way to go here, not one big shell string, as then you have more control over what happens. `bash -c ...` or `bash x.sh` may be what you want. You can also open `bash` directly and use `stdin` to supply the script by writing to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming you want the shell builtin `pushd`, you'd need to explicitly call bash in your system command, as ruby doesn't reference your $SHELL variable.  Something like:

```
require 'open3'
require 'shellwords'
Open3.popen3("bash -c #{Shellwords.escape(cmd)}")
```

should do the trick.